# Is a for loop in a function completed before performing code after the function?

Tags: ios, swift, function, for-loop

If I run this code:

```
 fanoutObj = fanoutPost(followersList.uid, followers: followersSnap, post: post)
 print(fanoutObj)
```

And the fanoutPost function has a really long for loop in it, then will will all the code in the function including the entire for loop be completed before the print(fanoutObj) runs?

Comment: Add breakpoint and you will get the answer of your own question.

Comment: Correct. It will execute everything synchronously, which means in a linear order. It has to run through every line of code prior to moving on to the next, which means your function completes before the print.

Comment: It depends on how the `fanoutPost` method is written. It may or may not return before fully completing. Without seeing your code we can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the placement of the `for` loop:

- If the `for` loop is in the body of the function directly, the answer is "yes", because all statements on the path to the end of the function or to the return statement must complete before the function returns.
- If the `for` loop is in a closure which does not get called in the function itself, gets called asynchronously, or is executed on a separate queue, the answer is "no", because only the registration of the callback must complete, while the callback itself runs separately.

One simple way to find out is to use breakpoints or debug output to check the relative order of execution.